# Textbox validation only works the first time round

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, textbox

I'm checking for blank textboxes after a button click using the following code:

```
if (address1Txt.Text.Trim().Length != 0 || address2Txt.Text.Trim().Length != 0 || postcodeTxt.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
{
    if (boardTypeDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString() != "")
    {
                 ...
    else
    {
        errorLbl.Text = "please select a board type";
    }
}
else
{
    errorLbl.Text = "please enter a value";
}
```

It works the first time I use it. But when I do the following it doesn't seem to validate the textboxes:

1. enter valid input
2. press button
3. delete the values
4. press button (no error label)

Same goes if I deselect the dropdown box value.

Comment: your code executes 2nd time when you press button ?

Comment: Please, post the code where you assign the event to this code.

Comment: This isn't Classic ASP.

Comment: Are you sure, you are deleting values from all of 3 textbox?

Comment: yeah the code executes.. Yes all text boxes are empty when I'm pressing the button.

Comment: IN which event you have written code for validation?

Comment: Also you have put OR condition. Are you sure you are doing what you mention for all controls.

Comment: inside the click event. Yes I'm sure, it wouldn't work the first time if I hadnt surely?